# Netflix Ribbon throws No instances available for MY-MICROSERVICE exception

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

My application uses Eureka and Ribbon. I'm trying to get two microservices to talk to each other. Below is my method of concern.

```
@Autowired @LoadBalanced
private RestTemplate client;

@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient dClient;

public String getServices() {      
    List<String> services = dClient.getServices();
    List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> serviceHosts = new ArrayList<>();       

    for(String service : services) {
        serviceInstances.addAll(dClient.getInstances(service));
    }

    for(ServiceInstance service : serviceInstances) {
       serviceHosts.add(service.getHost());
    }        

    //throws No instances available exception here
    try {
        System.out.println(this.client.getForObject("http://MY-MICROSERVICE/rest/hello", String.class, new HashMap<String, String>()));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return serviceHosts.toString();
}
```

The method returns an array of two hostnames(IP). So DiscoveryClient is able to see instances of the two services registered with Eureka. But RestTemplate or more precisely Ribbon throws IllegalStateExcpetion: No instances available exception.

```
DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client MY-MICROSERVICE initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=MY-MICROSERVICE,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@23edc38f
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for MY-MICROSERVICE
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99)
        at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58)
```

Even the Eureka dashboard shows two services registered. I feel the problem is specifically with Ribbon. Here's my config file.

```
spring.application.name="my-microservice"

logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=INFO

spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
spring.devtools.add-properties=true

server.ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

The other microservice also has the same configs except for a different name. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was using application.yml with Eureka-server and application.properties with the client. Once I converted everything to yml, all works fine.

```
spring:
 application:
  name: "my-microservice"
 devtools:
  restart:
   enabled: true
  add-properties: true

logging:
 level:
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging: INFO

eureka:
 client:
  serviceUrl:
   defaultZone: "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
```

This is the yml file for both apps which only differ by the application name.